# Changing the scopes on an existing live Bigcommerce app

Tags: bigcommerce

We're working on updating a Bigcommerce app (Previously submitted and currently live). It just so happens that we need to modify the scopes needed (we need access to products now).

Once changed, will our app go into pending mode and require resubmit? Will there be down time? if so, what will happen to current users that have the apps installed will they be able to use the parts of the app that use the scopes we already have permissions for?

Also, Will the current customers be prompted to approve of the new scopes the next time they try to start our application? how is this done?

Comment: Bigcommerce just announced a change to the oauth flow. When they release it, it will allow you to do this.

Comment: You're right, turns out they just enabled this today. Now everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

After a change on the BigCommerce end, this is something you are able to do within the [Developer Portal](https://devtools.bigcommerce.com) There's more info available about the scope update flow [here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#app-installation-and-update-sequence).